# Testing console output using a mock TextWriter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am trying to write a unit test for a class that outputs to the console. To capture the console output from this class I decided to create a mock TextWriter object and redirect the console output to it within the test class.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
    var outLines = new List<string>();
    var mockWriter = new Mock<TextWriter>();
    mockWriter.Setup(writer => writer.WriteLine(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Callback<string>(s => outLines.Add(s));
    Console.SetOut(mockWriter.Object);

    // ConsoleLogger is the class being tested
    // It will essentially just print its parameter to the console.
    var logger = new ConsoleLogger();
    logger.Error("foo");

    // Uncommenting this will cause the test to pass
    // Console.WriteLine("foo");

    Assert.AreEqual(1, outLines.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual("foo", outLines[0]);
}
```

This code does not work. However if I do a Console.WriteLine("foo") within the test it will work.

Even more strangely when debugging the test the console from the Logger class is still being redirected seemingly to nowhere as the unit test does not output anything asides from the Assert exceptions.

So basically my question is why does the mock code not get run when writing from the logger class?

Comment: Why use a mock? Just create a `StringWriter`, and then check it afterwards... that way you're not relying on the precise set of calls made. (For example, `ConsoleLogger` could be calling `Write` instead of `WriteLine`.)

Comment: I probably will end up using a string writer I am just trying to understand why the above code doesn't work. Also I wrote the ConsoleLogger so I know it uses WriteLine. I am just confused really.

Comment: Well, it may be calling `Console.WriteLine`, but that's not the same as it calling `WriteLine` on the underlying writer. Now if `ConsoleLogger` calls `Console.Out.WriteLine`, that would be more suspicious (though still explicable). This is the problem with mocking - you're making it really quite fragile.

Comment: Just changed it to use `Console.out.WriteLine` and the problem still persists. I am going to change the test but still am curious to know why this fails.

Comment: Consider creating a `TextWriter` which logs every call it gets... that would help diagnose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason must be that your `ConsoleLogger` class (whose code you have not shown?) actually calls [another overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.writeline.aspx) or another method.

If that other member is `virtual` or `abstract`, Moq will override it. Since you provided no `Setup` for the other overload, Moq will provide the "empty" implementation with a **loose** mock, or will throw an exception with a **strict** mock. Try changing into:

```
var mockWriter = new Mock<TextWriter>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

to see if such an exception helpfully occurs. My guess: It is the overload `WriteLine(object)`. It is often a good idea to use strict mocks.

However, if that other member is non-virtual, Moq has no chance of modifying its implementation. Then the implementation from the original class `TextWriter` will be used. That implementation might call a different member which *is* virtual, and you may `Setup` that.