# Testing false input in a C# method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, asp.net-web-api

So I'm trying to test a method which takes a city name and calls the OpenWeatherMap Web API by entering in a fake city name but I have absolutely no idea how to do that as all the examples I have encountered so far have been testing classes instead of methods.

How do I go about passing a fake city name to the method? Also, the method to call the API returns a Task so how would I be able to check the output string?

I am completely new to the realm of testing so any help would be much appreciated. I have also included my method code here.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string output;

        //Declare variables
        string strUserLocation;

        //Prompt user for city name
        Console.Write("Enter your city name: ");
        strUserLocation = Console.ReadLine();

        try
        {
            //Retrieve data from API
            Task<string> callTask = Task.Run(() => CallWebAPI(strUserLocation));
            callTask.Wait();

            //Get the result
            output = callTask.Result;
            Console.WriteLine(output);

            if(output == "Invalid city name. \n")
            {
                Main();
            }

            else
            {
                //Quit application
                Console.WriteLine("Press the ENTER key to quit the application.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid city name. \n");
            Main();
        }
    }//end Main


    //Method to call OpenWeatherMap API
    static async Task<string> CallWebAPI(string location)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Set base URI for HTTP requests
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"); 

            //Tells server to send data in JSON format
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            string strLocation = location;
            string strKey = "keyplaceholder123";

            //Send request and await response from server
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("?q=" + strLocation + "&APPID=" + strKey);

            if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                CurrentWeather weather = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CurrentWeather>().Result;

                //Convert temperature from Kelvin to Fahrenheit
                float temp = weather.main.temp * 1.8f - 459.67f;
                string strTempFahrenheit = temp.ToString("n0");

                //Display output
                return "The temperature in " + weather.name + " is " + strTempFahrenheit + "°F. \n";
            }

            else
            {
                return "Invalid city name. \n";
            }
        }//end using
    }//end CallWebAPI
```

Test that I have so far

```
    using System;
    using TechnicalExercise;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    namespace TechnicalExercise.Test
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class InputTest
        {
                [TestMethod]
                public void UserInput_EnterFakeCity_ReturnError()
                {
                    //Arrange
                    string strFakeCity = "Fake Lake City";
                    string expected = "Invalid city name. \n";
                    string actual;

                    //Act - Retrieve data from API
                    Task<string> callTask = Task.Run(() => CallWebAPI(strFakeCity));
                    callTask.Wait();
                    actual = callTask.Result;

                    //Assert - Checks if the actual result is as expected
                    Assert.Equals(actual, expected);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Testing is the same in all languages. If you want to test the output *return* the output. Don't write it to the console

Comment: Is the city name not `location`? And then it's passed to `client.GetAsync` (after assigning it to another string named `strLocation`, for some reason)? Also, which method are you referring to that's `void`?

Comment: @RufusL yeah location is the city name and the sorry I just realised the method is not void but returns a Task but what I wanted to check for was the output variable. I dont know how to pass a fake city name to the method and check if it returns the correct output string.

Comment: May be of interest: [Testing console output using a mock TextWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615557/testing-console-output-using-a-mock-textwriter).

Comment: If you showed the rest of the method (like the return statement), that might help some. Usually these types of methods return an `async Task<T>`, and the return value is actually of type `T`. So you would just use that as your result. It appears this method *is* void, so it just returns a `Task`. But you could certainly return `weather` instead. Then for input strings I guess you'd try `null`, `empty`, invalid cities, valid cities, utf-16 characters, sql statements, html encoded strings, uri values, etc. (depending on what kind of testing you're talking about).

Comment: Posting your `strKey` on here might go against the T&C's for `openweathermap.org`.

Comment: @Enigmativity The key that was on here was just a random string that I wrote but to avoid any further confusion I have replaced it with a more obvious placeholder. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks I have now changed my code to return a Task<string> instead of just a Task. 
my main problem is that I don't know if it is possible/how to pass a parameter to the method from a unit test as I have never done it before and all the examples I have found have shown been using a the method of instatiating a class then checking the value of their output property within that class whereas my application only has a method that I want to test

Comment: @RufusL Sorry just edited my code to show that so hopefully it looks clearer. I think I might have been a bit confusing in my original post but the problem with my testing scripts is that I have no idea how to pass a test parameter (for instance: an invalid city) to the method from my test project.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase you didnt figure it out yet here is the code!
I would also recommend you to take a look at async await and task because these things can be complicated!

Please notice the `Task<string>` and the `returns`instead of `output =`

```
    static async Task<string> CallWebAPI(string location)
    {
        //string output;

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Set base URI for HTTP requests
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather");

            //Tells server to send data in JSON format
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            string strLocation = location;
            string strKey = "427hdh9723797rg87";

            //Send request and await response from server
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("?q=" + strLocation + "&APPID=" + strKey);

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                CurrentWeather weather = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CurrentWeather>().Result;

                //Convert temperature from Kelvin to Fahrenheit
                float temp = weather.main.temp * 1.8f - 459.67f;
                string strTempFahrenheit = temp.ToString("n0");

                //Display output
                return "The temperature in " + weather.name + " is " + strTempFahrenheit + "°F. \n";
            }

            else
            {
                return "Invalid city name. \n";
                //Console.WriteLine(output);
                Main();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped to solve my problem with the void Task method! I have now changed my code to this.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with figuring out how to pass a parameter to a method instead of instantiating a class and testing that so if you could offer any advice on that I would be very grateful!

Comment: Your welcome :P,
if you mean with task i would recommend you to go async all the way. With that i mean that if you for example have a ui and backend you will not run it in the same Thread because the ui will get stuck because you will have the await a thread result in the backend. The thread can be called like this var result = await CallWebApi(location); But the function where the await will appear has to be a async methode to because it has to await something.

Please select my answer as answer if it solved your problem. It might help others :P